# jQuery animate() after hiding all but one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

```
$(".fader").click(function (e) { 


    $('.fader').not('#' + $(this).attr("id")).fadeOut(function() {

        $($(this).attr("id")).animate({width: "200",height: "200px", top: "-=-440px", left: "-=-367px"});

    });
});
```

fading out works, `animate()` works too but with different elements.
Is it the syntax to blame or my CSS that is blocking `animate()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to do `$($(this).attr("id"))` as `$(this)` is fine.

Also, the inner jQuery selector changes the meaning of 'this' to be different. If you want it to stay the same, you need to keep a reference to it first e.g.

```
$(".fader").click(function (e) { 

    var self = this;
    $('.fader').not(self).fadeOut(function() {

        $(self).animate({width: "200",height: "200px", top: "-=440px", left: "-=367px"});

    });
});
```

Comment: OK. it works now, but only outside that `fadeOut()` function, inside it still doesn't fire up.

Comment: Ah just noticed your syntax was wrong, should be '-=' not '-=-'. If it still doesn't work, can you put up a jsfiddle ?

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/J6DP9/1/) - I've made a jsfiddle, but it ignores `display: none` specification, don't know why.